# Can Flask-wtf show dynamic html. ie Update html based on drop-down selections

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

Here's my little test flask app using flask-wtf forms.

So when you choose a battery size and a usable capacity, I'd like to update the on-screen HTML whenever a different pulldown option is chosen.  So they can see the effect of the options before hitting submit.

So there are two parts I think?

1. Do some maths ie. (battery_size / 100) * battery_usable
2. then auto-update the screen

I've been looking at javascript, but I can't find anything to suits the set of circumstances. Can anyone point me in the right direction, please? Thanks.

**HTML**

```html
<form action="" method="post" novalidate>
   {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
   {{ form.csrf_token }}
   <br>
   {{ form.battery_size.label }}
   {{ form.battery_size }}
   <br>
   {{ form.battery_usable.label }}
   {{ form.battery_usable }}
   <br>
   {{ form.battery_size.data }}


   I want to show something like: 90% of 3.6kWh = 3.24kWh
   <br>
   <br>
   {{ form.submit }}
</form>
```

**Python**

```py
class TestForm(FlaskForm):
        fields = [(1.2, '1.2kWh'),(2.4, '2.4kWh'), (3.6, '3.6kWh'), (4.8, '4.8kWh'), (7.2, '7.2kWh'), (40, '40kWh')]
        battery_size = SelectField('Battery Size ', choices = fields, default=3.6, validate_choice=False)

        fields = [(10, '10%'), (20, '20%'), (30, '30%'), (40, '40%'),(50, '50%'), (60, '60%'), (70, '70%'), (80, '80%'), (90,'90%'), (100,'100%')]
        battery_usable = SelectField('How much of your battery is usable ', choices = fields, default=90, validate_choice=False)

        submit = SubmitField("Calculate Stuff")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen for the [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event on the form. This event will be triggered whenever an option of one of the `<select>` elements will be selected.

In the event handler get the values of both selects and use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to turn the `value` (which is a string) to a floating point number. Then do your calculation and output your result in a string wherever you want. In this case I've used an [`<output>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output) element as this would be semantically appropriate.

Optionally use the [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method on the result to the calculation to round the result to, for example, 2 decimals.

```js
const batteryForm = document.querySelector('.js-battery-form');

batteryForm.addEventListener('change', event => {
  const size = parseFloat(batteryForm.elements.size.value);
  const usable = parseFloat(batteryForm.elements.usable.value);
  const outputValue = (size / 100) * usable;
  batteryForm.elements.output.value = `${usable}% of ${size}kWh = ${outputValue.toFixed(2)}kWh`;
});
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<form class="js-battery-form">
  <label for="battery-size">Battery size</label>
  <select id="battery-size" name="size">
    <option value="1.2">1.2kWh</option>
    <option value="2.4">2.5kWh</option>
    <option value="3.6" selected>3.6kWh</option>
    <option value="4.8">4.8kWh</option>
    <option value="7.2">7.2kWh</option>
    <option value="40">40kWh</option>
  </select>
  <label for="battery-usable">Battery percentage usable</label>
  <select id="battery-usable" name="usable">
    <option value="10">10%</option>
    <option value="20">20%</option>
    <option value="30">30%</option>
    <option value="40">40%</option>
    <option value="50">50%</option>
    <option value="60">60%</option>
    <option value="70">70%</option>
    <option value="80">80%</option>
    <option value="90" selected>90%</option>
    <option value="100">100%</option>
  </select>
  <label for="battery-output">Output</label>
  <output id="battery-output" for="battery-size battery-usable" name="output">90% of 3.6kWh = 3.24kWh</output>
</form>
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you for taking the time to provide such a detailed answer.

Comment: Is there anyway something similar can be done using flask-wtf forms instead?  Your solution has now left me with a bunch of variables within the javascript that I don't know how to get back to the Python Flask code.

Comment: Nah, mate. But you can send your data to Python through submitting the form (with an  `action` attribute on the form that points to your Flask controller) or through JS with AJAX request. The JS I've provided only makes a calculation for the frontend. The HTML already has the necessary values for you to work with in your Flask controller.

Comment: All sorted, no need to get those variables out of JS.  I've just recalculated the values I needed in Flask based on the form choices.  Thanks again.